# Explain grafana query

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have a not working graph using this query:

```
100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",instance=~"$instance"}[$interval])) * 100) * ON(instance) GROUP_LEFT(host)
```

if I remove `* ON(instance) GROUP_LEFT(host)` the graph works.

Could you explain to me how to make this query work?

Thanks.

In addition to the above:

(1)

```
100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",instance=~"10.0.97.98:9100|10.0.97.97:9100|10.0.97.96:9100"}[5m])) * 100)
```

return

```
Element Value
{instance="10.0.97.97:9100"}    3.116666666852936    
{instance="10.0.97.98:9100"}    7.8333333328676815    
{instance="10.0.97.96:9100"}    2.116666666697725
```

and

(2)

```
host
```

return

```
Element Value
host{host="myhost1.com",instance="10.0.97.98:9100",job="node-exporter",node="i7986xnh9csf8lwavem4la8c9"}    1
host{host="myhost2.com",instance="10.0.97.97:9100",job="node-exporter",node="3s7mtcig78qr7ydducorurw4x"}    1
host{host="myhost3.com",instance="10.0.97.96:9100",job="node-exporter",node="8g6trw7q8tia07v3crlsb5izc"}    1
```

(1),(2) - instant vectors

Comment: You are missing a vector expression at the end of the expression. ` * ON(instance) GROUP_LEFT(host)` means multiply by another (missing) vector taking `instance` as criteria, the left hand side having higher cardinality and matching `host`.

Comment: @Michael Doubez thank you, I just added host at the end

Comment: From the data, you don't need `GROUP_LEFT`.